# Automated builds from Github

Tags: c#, github, jenkins, build

I want to automate builds of my project from Github repository. It is a C# project. Can I use Jenkins or anything similar to do that? I have used Jenkins with Java for Maven projects but I have never used it with Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [GitHub](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) plugin which should get you started

> This plugin integrates Jenkins with Github projects.
>
> The plugin currently has three major functionalities:
>
> Create hyperlinks between your Jenkins projects and GitHub Trigger a
>   job when you push to the repository by groking HTTP POSTs from
>   post-receive hook and optionally auto-managing the hook setup. Report
>   build status result back to github as Commit Status (documented on SO)

As to how to build a MS project, there is a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin) for that too

> To use this plugin, specify the location directory of MSBuild.exe on
>   Jenkin's configuration page. The MSBuild executable is usually
>   situated in a subfolder of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework. If you
>   have multiple MSBuild versions installed, you can configure multiple
>   executables.
>
> Then, on your project configuration page, specify the name of the
>   build file (.proj or .sln) and any command line arguments you want to
>   pass in. The files are compiled to the directory where Visual Studio
>   would put them as well.